# Using iPhone/Mac Continuity Camera on the web

Tags: javascript, macos, getusermedia, navigator, continuity

How to use iOS and macOS's latest feature of [Continuity Camera](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213244) feature with JavaScript, or how to avoid it from popping up in the process of requesting media devices, i.e. `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })`? - as it actually breaks this code on Chrome whenever my iPhone is close to the laptop with the error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source`, even after I tried to set `chrome://settings/content/camera` to the original FaceTime HD Camera - seems Chrome just keeps trying to request iPhone as the webcam.

---

Update - To avoid Continuity Camera, I use this quick patch to prefer the FaceTime Camera if possible (while it would still be better and cool to be able to use iPhone whenever needed)

```
let preferredDeviceId = undefined
const availableDevices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
if (availableDevices.length > 1)
    for (let d of availableDevices)
        if (d.label.includes('FaceTime'))
            preferredDeviceId = d.deviceId

await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        deviceId: preferredDeviceId,
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried to use `enumerateDevices()` but I'm not getting the continuity camera, are you still able to get it with no additional steps?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to either. Sorry for the confusion, but I think the problem above was Chrome thought CC was registered and fed it the default if you try to `getUserMedia` directly, while JavaScript couldn't load it, so I added the code snippet to prefer FaceTime camera instead of having Chrome to give a default.